# memory management for static

Tags: c#

where the static variables and methods are stored.
in heap or stack and how these memories are released when not in use

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more context on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static variables are stored on the heap. I'm not sure what you mean by methods, but local variables to a method are stored on the stack.

The stack is released when you exit a method. When a method needs local variables, more stack is allocated. When the method exits, the memory is released.

The rest of memory goes on the heap, e.g. with the `new` operator. This is released once you release all references to an object:

```
Car myCar = new Car();

// Use your car.

myCar = null;

// Somewhere between this point and when your application
// exits, the memory will be released.
```

The same goes for static variables, but you specifically must set these to `null` if you want to make them eligible for garbage collection.

For more information on .NET memory management, Google search results on http://www.google.com/search?q=memory+management+.net+heap+stack gave a few nice articles.

Comment: So if suppose we have a method with static key work b4 it. so i mean where this method allocate the memory in heap or stack and if in some static memory then when we don't use this method how it's memory is deallocated this i wan to know

Comment: How a method i can set explicitly for GC

Comment: A static method is just a method. Local variables for that method just go on the stack. A static method itself does not use memory, only it's parameters and local variables which all go on the stack.

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more context on what you are trying to accomplish. It looks like you're trying to do something specific, but without more information it is difficult to help you further.

Comment: and where the class variable goes in what memory... i am confuse with when we create an object what exactly happens what that object holds and how it allocated memory and for whom it allocates memory please sir explain me on this also i am really confuse

Comment: Class variables (fields and properties) go on the heap as part of the class.

Comment: sir i am novice to oops realm i am learning these oops concept so making me trouble understanding things and i am getting confuse a lot that's why i am stuck on this sort f questions

Comment: Thats what i am confuse with u say that "Class variables (fields and properties) go on the heap as part of the class" so class fields  are stored in heap that i got ok, but properties meas method and it consist of variables and some logic which are local to method then all this shud go in the stack only how come properties are also stored in heap also that make me confuse please elaborate me on this sir

Comment: With properties in this case I refer to auto properties: `public string MyProperty { get; set; }`. These are backed by actual fields which you don't see. Sorry for the confusion, you are correct :).

Comment: I expanded the answer with a Google search query which gave a few very nice articles (read a few of them). That could help further your understanding of .NET memory management.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/codeconcepts.aspx) gives a good explanation: static variables are stored on a special area of the heap in .net.

Comment: still that article lacking in some points well i will list all later what makes me very confuting